# JAVA IF ELSE Statement causes error in my code

Tags: java, compiler-errors, cannot-find-symbol

```
        Part part = request.getPart("file");
        if (part != null){
        String fileName = extractFileName(part);
        String filePath = savePath + File.separator + fileName;
        part.write(savePath + File.separator + fileName);
        String imageName = fileName;
        } else{
            String fileName = "avatar.jpg";
            String filePath = savePath + File.separator + fileName;
            part.write(savePath + File.separator + fileName);
            String imageName = fileName;
        }
```

After inserting the if else statement into the code, my code at the bottom gotten this error saying: imageName cannot be resolved to a variable and  filePath cannot be resolved to a variabl. However, once i comment away my if else statement everything is fine. Can someone tell me where is the error?

```
        request.setAttribute("Pic", filePath);
        request.setAttribute("PicName", imageName);
```

Answer (score 5):

Your "filePath" and "imageName" variables are only visible from within the if or else blocks. Declare these variables before the if/then blocks and then set the variable in the if/then code rather than re-declaring it.

```
String filePath = "";
String imageName = "";
if (...) {
...
} else {
...
}
request.setAttribute("Pic", filePath);
request.setAttribute("PicName", imageName);
```

See http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html for more information on scopes.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with @CConrad96. However, there are even more improvements that could be done, for example, the last 3 lines on the `if` and `else` are the same. Also, if you will write `imageName = fileName` why not get rid of one ? Last, the argument on `part.write` and has the same value as `filePath`, why not use it ?

```
String fileName:
Part part = request.getPart("file");
if (part != null){
    fileName = extractFileName(part);
} else{
    fileName = "avatar.jpg";
}

String filePath = savePath + File.separator + fileName;
part.write(filePath);

request.setAttribute("Pic", filePath);
request.setAttribute("PicName", fileName);
```

Comment: After adding this seems to work thank alots!!!

Comment: Sorry, but this code doesnt seem to work as it gave me this error: java.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Nanyang Polytechnic\FYPJ Project2\FYPJ\WebContent\profile (Access is denied)

Comment: Are you having this error in the code I wrote ? I think my code is OK, if your program is not allowed to access some directories, it's not the code's fault, is your fault. Check the file is where you wanted it to be, or maybe move it to a simpler loction, (like *C:/resources/[files_here]*. There is no way for me to know why you don't have access to that directory.